# Suppress SQLPLUS <p> paragraph tags when spooling to HTML

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I am using SQLPLUS with SET MARKUP HTML ON and I'll like to remove the paragraph tags that SQLPLUS adds before and after every table. The reason for this is because I am spooling the header of the data separately from the data (in order to avoid additional headers every 50 000 records), and I do not want a break between them.

Comment: Try adding the following commands in your SQL script SET PAGESIZE 0 SET HEADING OFF.

Comment: I have tried this already - does not work. Thanks for suggesting though.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is almost a year old already, but I came across the same (or a similar) issue and found a work-around.

Though I could not suppress the <p> automatically generated by SQLPLUS, I found this to be effective in that it negated the extra lines associated with the <p> tags:

HEAD " p {margin:0; padding:0; }"